# Does E. coli survive at any pH level?

Tags: bacteriology

Does E. coli survive at any pH level? If I was to incubate it in agar of different pH, would it still form a bacterial lawn as it's called?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are asking if *E. coli* can survive extreme pH conditions and according to [this study](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0056796) *E. coli* K-12 W3110 survives at pH 1.2 – pH 2.0 under low oxygen. This study cultured different strans overnight and exposed to pH 2.0 for 2 hours before diluting 1:80,000 and 1:400,000, under anoxic and aerated conditions. Dilutions where then plated allowing colonies to grow up overnight at 37 oC so this study measured survival as far as I can tell. *E. coli* can demonstrate robustness and *E. coli* survives and grows 'accustomed' at pH 7-8 based on the paper [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/11337868/Optimal-Conditions-for-the-Growth-of-E-Coli). However it would be great if you clarified your agar pH and the *E. coli* genetic background you are interested in if you have a specific question about its particular limits (growth or survival).

Comment: Also you need to clarify - grow, or merely survive?

Comment: @AlanBoyd I made further clarification/amendments to my response to state what the studies mentioned have measured, as requested to clarify my response. Many thanks for the pointer.